# Update ViewHolder values on click without updating content list in ListView

Tags: android, listview

Is it possible to update text, when I clicked on ListView row
without reinitializing all content list?

notifyDataSetChanged in the code below is not working:

```
    override fun selectView(chosenItemView: View?) {
    chosenItemView?.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)

    val item = chosenItemView?.tag as ListAdapter.MyHolder // right item found
    item.name.text = "Another text when on clicked"

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

Comment: utilize the adapter's `notifyItemInserted(int position)`.

Comment: @codeFreak `notifyItemInserted` is RecyclerView.Adapter method, not ListView

Comment: Sorry I meant try switching to a recyclerview and using the method mentioned above.